# Make Roundcube read Postfix's vhost Maildir files directly

Tags: postfix, roundcube

My current Postifx configuration is setup to receive only and I store all received mails in `/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/account/` in Maildir format.

Currently I use `mutt` to read these mails.

Is there any way I could configure Roundcube webmail to browse these mails without installing Dovecot or other IMAP/POP3 handlers? No need to send e-mails, just read only.

Comment: i am also looking for some php script with this functionality